# How can I share portfolio projects with Microsoft Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, rpa

I have an RPA job interview coming up and I want to make portfolio projects that I can share using Microsoft Power Automate.  My question is, how can I share my projects I make?  I can't figure out how to hook up version control, when I google version control it sometimes says you can't do this which sounds really weird to me, and if someone can help me out by telling me how to do this I would be very appreciative.  I currently only have the free version running but I wouldn't have a problem upgrading if this will solve my problem.  If there is a free way to do this though that would be better.  Thanks!

Comment: Define “Portfolio Projects” for us